# flask.cli.NoAppException: The file/path provided (new_app.py) does not appear to exist

Tags: python, flask

I keep getting this error `flask.cli.NoAppException: The file/path provided (new_app.py) does not appear to exist.  Please verify the path is correct. If app is not on PYTHONPATH, ensure the extension is .py` it goes away after I restart the Flask server.

I am running `flask run` in the correct directory where my app is. This just started happening after working for 2 weeks. I've read that it could be due to an import error, but I am not finding any modules that are not installed on my virutalenv.

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)
app.debug=True
```

Answer (score 1):

Most likely  you haven't set the [`FLASK_APP` environment variable](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/quickstart/).

> To run the application you can either use the flask command or
>   python’s -m switch with Flask. Before you can do that you need to tell
>   your terminal the application to work with by exporting the FLASK_APP
>   environment variable:
>
> $ export FLASK_APP=hello.py
>
> $ flask run  * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/
>
> If you are on Windows you need to use set
>   instead of export.
>
> Alternatively you can use python -m flask:
>
> $ export FLASK_APP=hello.py
>
> $ python -m flask run  * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/

#### EDIT

If you have `FLASK_APP` set then try adding this to new_app.py

```
app.run(debug=True, port=8800)
```

Or if you're on Windows:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True, port=8800)
```

And then just execute the app with `python new_app.py`.

Comment: I have set `$export FLASK_APP=new_app.py` as well as `$ export FLASK_DEBUG=1`

Comment: Edited answer with another possible solution.

Comment: I'm in @RonArevalo's same boat and don't have an explanation for what was working and now isn't either...